# How to find stability of fixed point of a PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, fixed-points

I have a system of coupled PDEs which have both time and spatial dependence with the form:

\begin{align*} a_t &= D_aa_{xx}+f(a, b) \\ b_t &= D_bb_{xx}+g(a, b) \end{align*}

where $f(a, b)$ and $g(a, b)$ are linear functions in terms of $a$ and $b$ and $D_a$ and $D_b$ are diffusion coefficients.

When there is no spatial dependence I can easily calculate the fixed points, find the Jacobian and determine the stability of the fixed points.

My question is then, how can I generalise this method when I have spatial dependence too? I was told I could Fourier Transform the system and turn it into a set of ODEs so that I have

\begin{align*} \tilde{a}_t &= -k^2D_a\tilde{a}+f(\tilde{a}, \tilde{b}) \\ \tilde{b}_t &= -k^2D_b\tilde{b}+g(\tilde{a}, \tilde{b}) \end{align*}

and find the Jacobian of this. However, I struggle to see how finding the Jacobian of the Fourier transformed equations could be related to the stability of my system? I was also told that the Jacobian of my FT equations is equal to the Jacobian of my non transformed system though I can't figure out how.

Also:

$$\tilde{a}(k, t) = \int a(x, t)e^{ikx}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. You say you have a system of PDEs with both time and spatial dependence with which you apply your techniques, then you ask how you can apply it to a system with spatial dependence? Why don't you edit your post to include the full system and show us your working as to avoid any confusion.

Comment: no I applied the techniques on the homogeneous system - ie no spatial dependence.

Comment: Sorry, I've never heard of the term homogeneous being applied in that way before. Can you write out the full system and your working? If I know what the system looks like I might be able to give you some other approaches.

Comment: Sorry it took ages - I never used Latex with stackexchange before.

Comment: All good, it makes it much easier to help now. Your system is just a [reaction diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction–diffusion_system) problem. An often used technique is to make a _travelling wave ansatz_ i.e set $a(x,t) = u(x-ct) = u(z)$ and $b(x,t) = v(x-ct) = v(z)$, which turns your PDE system into an ODE system. You can then convert this to a **first order** ODE system, which you can then apply your techniques to.. Note here that $z$ is dependent on your spatial variable.The problem with using the FT approach as you suggested comes about if $f$ and $g$ are non-linear.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this approach. For future reference, if f and g are linear is the Jacobian of the FT system equal to the Jacobian of my non transformed system?